# Setup the bottom of the page AdMob banner

Tags: android, css, admob, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to setup an AdMob banner on the bottom of the page, but the Ad does not show.
Space appears the bottom of the page there, but the AdMob does not show there.

1. Add and reference the Google Play services library. - YES
2. Add a meta-data tag in AndroidManifest.xml. - YES
3. Declare com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity in the manifest. - YES
4. Set up network permissions in the manifest. - YES

Somebody tell me why. 
Thank you.

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContainer"                <!-- DATA Layout -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"                  <!-- AdMob Layout -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
// Create an ad.
adView = new AdView(context);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

// Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view
// will have no size
// until the ad is loaded.
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_layout);
//layout.getBottom();
layout.addView(adView);

// Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the
// hashed device ID to
// get test ads on a physical device.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE").build();

// Start loading the ad in the background.
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You told fldContainer to matchParent. THis means it will consume all the space of the parent, leaving none for your ad.

Instead try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContainer"                <!-- DATA Layout -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"                  <!-- AdMob Layout -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using a layout weight for the 'flContainer', I'd recommend a '0dp' height for that component.